# Access to AudioSource object when changing scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I need to update the `AudioSource.volume` of the MusicScript object.
On the `Awake` method of the MusicScript class I have:

```
void Awake()
 {
     GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("music");
     if (objs.Length > 1)
     {
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
     }
     DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
 }
```

But when switching scenes, the `musicScript.audioSource` is  destroyed.
How can I keep the `musicScript.audioSource` object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the full audioSource reference here. Is the AudioSource object attached to the gameobject tagged with "music"? Is the "musicScript" instance also attached to the gameobject tagged with "music"?

The way I would do it is by using the singleton method. Just make sure that the gameobject you want to persist between scenes has both the musicScript and the AudioSource component attached to it. And then add this code to your musicScript:

```
private void Awake()
 {
    // if the singleton hasn't been initialized yet
    if (instance != null && instance != this)
    {
       Destroy(this.gameObject);
       return;//Avoid doing anything else
    }
 
    instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
 }
```

Where "instance" should be a variable with the type of musicManager.

Source: https://answers.unity.com/questions/891380/unity-c-singleton.html

Comment: Yes, the musicScript class is attached to a object with the tag "music". But the problem is that it has to check if there are more than 2 objects with the tag "music", because if you change scenes and you go to the scene that has originally the object with the tag "music" it is going to multiply and play repeatly the music.

Comment: Yes. And it doesn't destroy the object, but the music object gets muitiplied

Comment: the "return" was the trick for my case, thank you!